# How to strip locale from path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization

In my Rails application I have this helper function:

```
def frontend_section_link(title, path)
  localized_title = t("pages.#{title}")
  options = {}  
  options[:class] = 'current' if current_page?(path)
  content_tag :li do 
    link_to localized_title, path, options
  end
end
```

I am using it in my view like this:

```
<ul id="main_navigation">
  <%= frontend_section_link(:features, features_path) %>
  <%= frontend_section_link(:pricing, pricing_path) %>  
  <%= frontend_section_link(:faq, faq_path) %>
</ul>
```

The problem is that it does not highlight a menu item after the user has just switched the language (e.g. from German to English).

I guess I'll have to get rid of the locale part in the URL of the `path`, however I don't know how to do that and I found that Rails' built-in `current_page?(path)` function only works when the locale is included in the `path`.

In other words, the function above should work only with the last segment of the URL, e.g. `/pricing/` even if the URL is *actually* `/en/pricing/`.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the locale of the session you can use it that way.  You can do so like:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_local
  I18n.locale = session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Then when they switch languages just set it on the session.